# getting input format

Tags: sas

So, I just buy introduction book for sas. But it only contain tons of examples with little/no explanation. I tried to find some tutorial online, but I can't find the explanation for this formatting. I just wonder what's the different between these two:

```
INPUT Name $16. Age 3. +1 height 5.1
```

I wonder, what does "." mean. What the different between:

```
INPUT Name $16
```

and

```
INPUT Name $ 1-16
```

what is the symbol "+1" mean?

what does "5.1" mean? how's that different from "5."? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formats always contain periods; the period can serve to separate width from decimal, ie 5.1 is 5 total width, 1 decimal - so `xxx.d` (actually, `-xx.d`, but it will also display `xxx.d` correctly).  For character values and other values that cannot have decimal portions, there is never a number after the period, but it is still present; so `DATE9.` is a DATE formatted variable (specifically, looks like "19JAN2013") and is 9 characters long (as opposed to `DATE7.`, or 19JAN13).

In general, SAS has many different input options.  Find a better book, or read the online documentation (http://support.sas.com/documentation/92/index.html or similar for your version of SAS).  `input Name $16.` inputs name as a 16 digit character variable.  You have a lot of variants of input options, so look at the documentation to find out more.

+1 specifically tells SAS to move the pointer forward one - so instead of 16 characters of Name, then 3 digits of Age, then 5 digits of Height, it skips a space between Age and Height; so `NAMENAMENAMENAMEage heigh` not `NAMENAMENAMENAMEageheigh`.

Answer (score 0):

You can start here:
[Input statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/63323/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0oaql83drile0n141pdacojq97s.htm)